# Why shouldn't one side of the Tailwind element's component sidenav work?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, sidenav

I use sidenav from tailwind element's components in two places. First is the category sidenav and the second is the cart sidenav. The category bar is on the left side, and when I click on the category button, it works. the cart bar is on the right side and when I click the button doesn't work. If "data-te-sidevan-hidden='false'" and when reload is shown and works when click outside is hidden and this function works but when I try open again it's not working it doesn't have a reaction. it's not working on shared hosting but works on localhost. I hope to explained well to my problem

I use this code for category sidenav

```html
<!-- Sidenav -->
<nav id="sidenav-1" class="absolute left-0 top-0 z-[1035] h-full w-60 -translate-x-full overflow-hidden bg-white shadow-[0_4px_12px_0_rgba(0,0,0,0.07),_0_2px_4px_rgba(0,0,0,0.05)] data-[te-sidenav-hidden='false']:translate-x-0 dark:bg-zinc-800" data-te-sidenav-init
  data-te-sidenav-hidden="false" data-te-sidenav-position="absolute">
  <ul class="relative m-0 list-none px-[0.2rem]" data-te-sidenav-menu-ref>
    <li class="relative">
      <a class="flex h-12 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] px-6 py-4 text-[0.875rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
        data-te-sidenav-link-ref>
        <span
          class="mr-4 [&>svg]:h-4 [&>svg]:w-4 [&>svg]:text-gray-400 dark:[&>svg]:text-gray-300">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke-width="1.5"
            stroke="currentColor"
            class="h-4 w-4">
            <path
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
              d="M15.182 15.182a4.5 4.5 0 01-6.364 0M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0zM9.75 9.75c0 .414-.168.75-.375.75S9 10.164 9 9.75 9.168 9 9.375 9s.375.336.375.75zm-.375 0h.008v.015h-.008V9.75zm5.625 0c0 .414-.168.75-.375.75s-.375-.336-.375-.75.168-.75.375-.75.375.336.375.75zm-.375 0h.008v.015h-.008V9.75z" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span>Link 1</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="relative">
      <a class="flex h-12 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] px-6 py-4 text-[0.875rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
        data-te-sidenav-link-ref>
        <span
          class="mr-4 [&>svg]:h-4 [&>svg]:w-4 [&>svg]:text-gray-400 dark:[&>svg]:text-gray-300">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            fill="currentColor"
            class="h-4 w-4">
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M12 2.25c-5.385 0-9.75 4.365-9.75 9.75s4.365 9.75 9.75 9.75 9.75-4.365 9.75-9.75S17.385 2.25 12 2.25zm-2.625 6c-.54 0-.828.419-.936.634a1.96 1.96 0 00-.189.866c0 .298.059.605.189.866.108.215.395.634.936.634.54 0 .828-.419.936-.634.13-.26.189-.568.189-.866 0-.298-.059-.605-.189-.866-.108-.215-.395-.634-.936-.634zm4.314.634c.108-.215.395-.634.936-.634.54 0 .828.419.936.634.13.26.189.568.189.866 0 .298-.059.605-.189.866-.108.215-.395.634-.936.634-.54 0-.828-.419-.936-.634a1.96 1.96 0 01-.189-.866c0-.298.059-.605.189-.866zm2.023 6.828a.75.75 0 10-1.06-1.06 3.75 3.75 0 01-5.304 0 .75.75 0 00-1.06 1.06 5.25 5.25 0 007.424 0z"
              clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span>Category 1</span>
        <span
          class="absolute right-0 ml-auto mr-[0.8rem] transition-transform duration-300 ease-linear motion-reduce:transition-none [&>svg]:text-gray-600 dark:[&>svg]:text-gray-300"
          data-te-sidenav-rotate-icon-ref>
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="currentColor"
            class="h-5 w-5">
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M5.23 7.21a.75.75 0 011.06.02L10 11.168l3.71-3.938a.75.75 0 111.08 1.04l-4.25 4.5a.75.75 0 01-1.08 0l-4.25-4.5a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06z"
              clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        </span>
      </a>
      <ul class="!visible relative m-0 hidden list-none p-0 data-[te-collapse-show]:block " data-te-sidenav-collapse-ref data-te-collapse-show>
        <li class="relative">
          <a class="flex h-6 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] py-4 pl-[3.4rem] pr-6 text-[0.78rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
            data-te-sidenav-link-ref>Link 2</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="relative">
          <a
            class="flex h-6 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] py-4 pl-[3.4rem] pr-6 text-[0.78rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
            data-te-sidenav-link-ref
            >Link 3</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="relative">
      <a
        class="flex h-12 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] px-6 py-4 text-[0.875rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
        data-te-sidenav-link-ref>
        <span
          class="mr-4 [&>svg]:h-4 [&>svg]:w-4 [&>svg]:text-gray-400 dark:[&>svg]:text-gray-300">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            fill="currentColor"
            class="h-4 w-4">
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M12 2.25c-5.385 0-9.75 4.365-9.75 9.75s4.365 9.75 9.75 9.75 9.75-4.365 9.75-9.75S17.385 2.25 12 2.25zm-2.625 6c-.54 0-.828.419-.936.634a1.96 1.96 0 00-.189.866c0 .298.059.605.189.866.108.215.395.634.936.634.54 0 .828-.419.936-.634.13-.26.189-.568.189-.866 0-.298-.059-.605-.189-.866-.108-.215-.395-.634-.936-.634zm4.314.634c.108-.215.395-.634.936-.634.54 0 .828.419.936.634.13.26.189.568.189.866 0 .298-.059.605-.189.866-.108.215-.395.634-.936.634-.54 0-.828-.419-.936-.634a1.96 1.96 0 01-.189-.866c0-.298.059-.605.189-.866zm2.023 6.828a.75.75 0 10-1.06-1.06 3.75 3.75 0 01-5.304 0 .75.75 0 00-1.06 1.06 5.25 5.25 0 007.424 0z"
              clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span>Category 2</span>
        <span
          class="absolute right-0 ml-auto mr-[0.8rem] transition-transform duration-300 ease-linear motion-reduce:transition-none [&>svg]:text-gray-600 dark:[&>svg]:text-gray-300"
          data-te-sidenav-rotate-icon-ref>
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="currentColor"
            class="h-5 w-5">
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M5.23 7.21a.75.75 0 011.06.02L10 11.168l3.71-3.938a.75.75 0 111.08 1.04l-4.25 4.5a.75.75 0 01-1.08 0l-4.25-4.5a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06z"
              clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        </span>
      </a>
          <ul class="show !visible relative m-0 hidden list-none p-0 data-[te-collapse-show]:block " data-te-sidenav-collapse-ref>
            <li class="relative">
              <a class="flex h-6 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] py-4 pl-[3.4rem] pr-6 text-[0.78rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
                data-te-sidenav-link-ref>Link 4</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="relative">
          <a
            class="flex h-6 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] py-4 pl-[3.4rem] pr-6 text-[0.78rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
            data-te-sidenav-link-ref
            >Link 5</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!-- Sidenav -->

<!-- Toggler -->
<button
  class="mt-10 inline-block rounded bg-primary px-6 py-2.5 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-tight text-white shadow-md transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:bg-primary-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-primary-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-primary-800 active:shadow-lg"
  data-te-sidenav-toggle-ref
  data-te-target="#sidenav-1"
  aria-controls="#sidenav-1"
  aria-haspopup="true">
  <span class="block [&>svg]:h-5 [&>svg]:w-5 [&>svg]:text-white">
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      fill="currentColor"
      class="h-5 w-5">
      <path
        fill-rule="evenodd"
        d="M3 6.75A.75.75 0 013.75 6h16.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5H3.75A.75.75 0 013 6.75zM3 12a.75.75 0 01.75-.75h16.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5H3.75A.75.75 0 013 12zm0 5.25a.75.75 0 01.75-.75h16.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5H3.75a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75z"
        clip-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>
  </span>
</button>
<!-- Toggler -->

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

And this is cart sidenav for right side which has a problem

```
<!-- Sidenav -->
<nav
  id="sidenav-7"
  class="fixed right-0 top-0 z-[1035] h-screen w-60 translate-x-full overflow-hidden bg-white shadow-[0_4px_12px_0_rgba(0,0,0,0.07),_0_2px_4px_rgba(0,0,0,0.05)] data-[te-sidenav-hidden='false']:-translate-x-0 dark:bg-zinc-800"
  data-te-sidenav-init
  data-te-sidenav-hidden="false"
  data-te-sidenav-right="true">
  <ul class="relative m-0 list-none px-[0.2rem]" data-te-sidenav-menu-ref>
    <li class="relative">
      <a
        class="flex h-12 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] px-6 py-4 text-[0.875rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
        data-te-sidenav-link-ref>
        <span
          class="mr-4 [&>svg]:h-4 [&>svg]:w-4 [&>svg]:text-gray-400 dark:[&>svg]:text-gray-300">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke-width="1.5"
            stroke="currentColor"
            class="h-4 w-4">
            <path
              stroke-linecap="round"
              stroke-linejoin="round"
              d="M15.182 15.182a4.5 4.5 0 01-6.364 0M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0zM9.75 9.75c0 .414-.168.75-.375.75S9 10.164 9 9.75 9.168 9 9.375 9s.375.336.375.75zm-.375 0h.008v.015h-.008V9.75zm5.625 0c0 .414-.168.75-.375.75s-.375-.336-.375-.75.168-.75.375-.75.375.336.375.75zm-.375 0h.008v.015h-.008V9.75z" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span>Link 1</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="relative">
      <a
        class="flex h-12 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] px-6 py-4 text-[0.875rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
        data-te-sidenav-link-ref>
        <span
          class="mr-4 [&>svg]:h-4 [&>svg]:w-4 [&>svg]:text-gray-400 dark:[&>svg]:text-gray-300">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            fill="currentColor"
            class="h-4 w-4">
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M12 2.25c-5.385 0-9.75 4.365-9.75 9.75s4.365 9.75 9.75 9.75 9.75-4.365 9.75-9.75S17.385 2.25 12 2.25zm-2.625 6c-.54 0-.828.419-.936.634a1.96 1.96 0 00-.189.866c0 .298.059.605.189.866.108.215.395.634.936.634.54 0 .828-.419.936-.634.13-.26.189-.568.189-.866 0-.298-.059-.605-.189-.866-.108-.215-.395-.634-.936-.634zm4.314.634c.108-.215.395-.634.936-.634.54 0 .828.419.936.634.13.26.189.568.189.866 0 .298-.059.605-.189.866-.108.215-.395.634-.936.634-.54 0-.828-.419-.936-.634a1.96 1.96 0 01-.189-.866c0-.298.059-.605.189-.866zm2.023 6.828a.75.75 0 10-1.06-1.06 3.75 3.75 0 01-5.304 0 .75.75 0 00-1.06 1.06 5.25 5.25 0 007.424 0z"
              clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span>Category 1</span>
        <span
          class="absolute right-0 ml-auto mr-[0.8rem] transition-transform duration-300 ease-linear motion-reduce:transition-none [&>svg]:text-gray-600 dark:[&>svg]:text-gray-300"
          data-te-sidenav-rotate-icon-ref>
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="currentColor"
            class="h-5 w-5">
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M5.23 7.21a.75.75 0 011.06.02L10 11.168l3.71-3.938a.75.75 0 111.08 1.04l-4.25 4.5a.75.75 0 01-1.08 0l-4.25-4.5a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06z"
              clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        </span>
      </a>
      <ul
        class="!visible relative m-0 hidden list-none p-0 data-[te-collapse-show]:block "
        data-te-sidenav-collapse-ref>
        <li class="relative">
          <a
            class="flex h-6 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] py-4 pl-[3.4rem] pr-6 text-[0.78rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
            data-te-sidenav-link-ref
            >Link 2</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="relative">
          <a
            class="flex h-6 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] py-4 pl-[3.4rem] pr-6 text-[0.78rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
            data-te-sidenav-link-ref
            >Link 3</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="relative">
      <a
        class="flex h-12 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] px-6 py-4 text-[0.875rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
        data-te-sidenav-link-ref>
        <span
          class="mr-4 [&>svg]:h-4 [&>svg]:w-4 [&>svg]:text-gray-400 dark:[&>svg]:text-gray-300">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            fill="currentColor"
            class="h-4 w-4">
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M12 2.25c-5.385 0-9.75 4.365-9.75 9.75s4.365 9.75 9.75 9.75 9.75-4.365 9.75-9.75S17.385 2.25 12 2.25zm-2.625 6c-.54 0-.828.419-.936.634a1.96 1.96 0 00-.189.866c0 .298.059.605.189.866.108.215.395.634.936.634.54 0 .828-.419.936-.634.13-.26.189-.568.189-.866 0-.298-.059-.605-.189-.866-.108-.215-.395-.634-.936-.634zm4.314.634c.108-.215.395-.634.936-.634.54 0 .828.419.936.634.13.26.189.568.189.866 0 .298-.059.605-.189.866-.108.215-.395.634-.936.634-.54 0-.828-.419-.936-.634a1.96 1.96 0 01-.189-.866c0-.298.059-.605.189-.866zm2.023 6.828a.75.75 0 10-1.06-1.06 3.75 3.75 0 01-5.304 0 .75.75 0 00-1.06 1.06 5.25 5.25 0 007.424 0z"
              clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span>Category 2</span>
        <span
          class="absolute right-0 ml-auto mr-[0.8rem] transition-transform duration-300 ease-linear motion-reduce:transition-none [&>svg]:text-gray-600 dark:[&>svg]:text-gray-300"
          data-te-sidenav-rotate-icon-ref>
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="currentColor"
            class="h-5 w-5">
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M5.23 7.21a.75.75 0 011.06.02L10 11.168l3.71-3.938a.75.75 0 111.08 1.04l-4.25 4.5a.75.75 0 01-1.08 0l-4.25-4.5a.75.75 0 01.02-1.06z"
              clip-rule="evenodd" />
          </svg>
        </span>
      </a>
      <ul
        class="show !visible relative m-0 hidden list-none p-0 data-[te-collapse-show]:block "
        data-te-sidenav-collapse-ref>
        <li class="relative">
          <a
            class="flex h-6 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] py-4 pl-[3.4rem] pr-6 text-[0.78rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
            data-te-sidenav-link-ref
            >Link 4</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="relative">
          <a
            class="flex h-6 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] py-4 pl-[3.4rem] pr-6 text-[0.78rem] text-gray-600 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-inherit hover:outline-none focus:bg-slate-50 focus:text-inherit focus:outline-none active:bg-slate-50 active:text-inherit active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-inherit data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
            data-te-sidenav-link-ref
            >Link 5</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!-- Sidenav -->

<!-- Toggler -->
<button
  class="mt-10 inline-block rounded bg-primary px-6 py-2.5 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-tight text-white shadow-md transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:bg-primary-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-primary-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-primary-800 active:shadow-lg"
  data-te-sidenav-toggle-ref
  data-te-target="#sidenav-7"
  aria-controls="#sidenav-7"
  aria-haspopup="true">
  <span class="block [&>svg]:h-5 [&>svg]:w-5 [&>svg]:text-white">
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      fill="currentColor"
      class="h-5 w-5">
      <path
        fill-rule="evenodd"
        d="M3 6.75A.75.75 0 013.75 6h16.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5H3.75A.75.75 0 013 6.75zM3 12a.75.75 0 01.75-.75h16.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5H3.75A.75.75 0 013 12zm0 5.25a.75.75 0 01.75-.75h16.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5H3.75a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75z"
        clip-rule="evenodd" />
    </svg>
  </span>
</button>
<!-- Toggler -->
```

Comment: Does the snippet demo I added above show the problem? If so, maybe the second code block isn't really needed. See [ask] for tips on simplifying your post.